# Hibernate's shenanigans -- I just want an unmanaged copy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've got a Java app using Spring, and Hibernate using the JPA 2.0 specification.

I'm trying to persist 100 "nodes" in a for loop. I persist each node as I make progress through the for loop, and sometimes I get some of the nodes I've already persisted to see if I want my new one to be a shallow clone of one of those, aside from its coordinates. (Basically I'm making a map, and sometimes I want my squares to be identical to each other.)

I've been having issues where not all of them I want to get persisted are being persisted, though, and it's hibernate/JPA screwing me up.

The entire thing takes place in one transaction.

```
int startingX = sn.getxCoor() * 10;
int startingY = sn.getyCoor() * 10;
for (int nodeX = startingX; nodeX < startingX + 10; nodeX++) {
    for (int nodeY = startingY; nodeY < startingY + 10; nodeY++) {
        ns.persistNodeIfNotExistent(this.generateNode(nodeX, nodeY, sn));
    }
}

public void persistNodeIfNotExistent(Node toPersist) {
    if (nd.getNode(toPersist.getxCoor(), toPersist.getyCoor()) == null) {
        nd.merge(toPersist);
    }
}


public Node generateNode(int nodeX, int nodeY, SuperNode sn) {
    Node newNode = nodeIsDuplicate(nodeX, nodeY);
    if (newNode == null) {
        newNode = new Node();
        [bunch of irrelevant stuff gets set]
    }
    newNode.setxCoor(nodeX);
    newNode.setyCoor(nodeY);
    return newNode;
}

public Node nodeIsDuplicate(int nodeX, int nodeY) {
    Node nodeToReturn = null;
    List<Node> adjacentNodes = ns.getAdjacentNodes(nodeX, nodeY);
    int chanceItsDuplicate = 20 * adjacentNodes.size();
    if (randomizer.randomInt99() < chanceItsDuplicate) {
        Node adjNode = adjacentNodes
                .get(randomizer.getRandom().nextInt(adjacentNodes.size()));
        ns.detach(adjNode);
        nodeToReturn = new Node();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(adjNode, nodeToReturn);
    }
    return nodeToReturn;
}
```

My first strategy to fix this whole mess was to use Spring's BeanUtils to copy the properties, which I thought would give me a non-managed copy, but they don't all get persisted, so it must not be. Then I added in the detach through my entityManager to try to make sure it was detached, but in the service layer I can still see that the "getNode" method turns up with a bunch of results, even though the database is wiped clean.

Is there any simple and sane way to copy my entities without Hibernate thwarting me at every turn?

Comment: The entity does have an ID which is separate from its coordinates, and that is apparently being assigned, so maybe that's part of the issue here? If the id is an auto-generated int, though, how would I null it when copying if that's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my issue was that they had their primarykey, their Id, set to the primary key of the original node. When I manually set the Id of the copies to 0, it worked. I'm using MySQL, so not sure if that would work with other databases, but considering a java "int" always has a default value of 0, it should.

Comment: You're right, when reattaching an entity to the session, Hibernate goes by its primary key to determine whether it's a new record or an update to an old record. In non-JPA Hibernate, what value that is is determined by the rarely-needed [`unsaved-value` mapping attribute](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id). The default is claimed to be "sensible", so I'm guessing it's whatever value the type would have for an uninitialised variable. (`0`, `null`, etc.)